# ORA-22835 using JPA (Buffer too small)

Tags: oracle, hibernate, orm, jpa, clob

I am trying to persist an Entity with a @Lob annotated String field.  The content of that fiels if bigger than the 40k buffer size limit.

The first problem I had was related to the setString method used internally by the JPA implementation (Hibernate in my case) and the Oracle JDBC Driver.  This problem was solved adding

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob" value="true"/>
```

to my persistence.xml file.

Then, the error changed to a ORA-22835 error (the buffer is too small).  ¿Is there any way that JPA solves this problem without going to a low-level implementation?   ¿Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of the Oracle JDBC driver are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can your try with [**Oracle 10g Release 2 drivers**](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/index.html) (pick up the most recent ojdbc14.jar i.e. 10.2.0.4) **or later** (older versions are buggy as mentioned in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115420/cannot-save-clob-data-type-in-database-struts-spring-hibernate/2130726#2130726)).

Comment: OK then...  I downloaded the last drivers (which I thought I already had, but I was wrong).

Now I have another error: ORA-24816  =>Expanded non LONG bind data supplied after actual LONG or LOB column

I have read that this is an Oracle issue.  Is there any way to make JPA (or the underlying implementation, Hibernate in my case) sort the columns in a given order so the Clob column comes last?  It looks like that's the problem I am having now...

Comment: The problem just vanished :S  I'm not very happy about it because what vanishes today can reappear tomorrow, but it sure looks like configuration issue.