# How to insert CLOB to Oracle using Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa, spring-data

I have problem with trying to save CLOB to Oracle using Spring Data and CRUDRepository interface. On the database side, column is of CLOB type. Strings shorter than 4000 characters are saved correctly, but longer - not (ORA-01461), despite the @Lob annotation and column definition parameter in @Column annotation. I couldn't find solution for this issue, because all I found relates to Spring JDBC Template, not Spring Data.

```
try (ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(messageBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        message = (DeadLetterMessage) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(inputStream));
    }

    try {
        message = repository.save(message);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        log.warn("### Failed to store message in database", e);
        throw e;
    }
```

Properties in persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="deadletter" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.lppsa.integration.camel.dlc.entity.DeadLetterMessage</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Problem is only with values longer than 4000.

```
(...)
@Lob
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "MESSAGE_DATA", columnDefinition = "CLOB NOT NULL")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ByteArrayXmlAdapter.class)
private byte[] messageData;
(...)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115420/cannot-save-clob-data-type-in-database-struts-spring-hibernate?rq=1 -> this does not work.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] including your current code.

Comment: I'm using default _save_ method from CRUDRepository interface.

Comment: You can use length property for @Column for Clob object like @Column( name = "MESSAGE_DATA", columnDefinition = "CLOB NOT NULL", length = 10000)

Comment: what is this "ByteArrayXmlAdapter" ?? ..and has it been tested with (utf-16 > 4000 strings)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolved. I used java.sql.Clob to wrap that column. I replaced ByteArrayXmlAdapter with ClobXmlAdapter (that was needed to correctly marshal object). For creating CLOB I have used NonContextualLobCreator, and, for serialization - I've wrapped it with SerializableClobProxy. Creating BLOB/CLOB is described here: [What is the alternate for deprecated Hibernate.createClob(Reader reader, int length)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304211/what-is-the-alternate-for-deprecated-hibernate-createclobreader-reader-int-len)